# not able to receive multicast data

Tags: c, networking

I am developing an application wherein I need to send and receive some multicast data. I have written a simple multicast data receiver program for testing purpose, but due to some reasons I am not able to receive the multicast data. This is my sample code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void* recvd(void* t)
{
    printf("thread created\n");

    long socket_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);

    struct sockaddr_in muladdr;
    memset(&muladdr,0,sizeof(muladdr));
    muladdr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    muladdr.sin_port=htons(3454);
    inet_aton("15.45.234.3",(in_addr*)&muladdr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    memset(&mreq,0,sizeof(mreq));
    inet_aton("224.1.2.3",(in_addr*)&mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr);
    inet_aton("15.45.234.3",(in_addr*)&mreq.imr_interface.s_addr);

    setsockopt(socket_fd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,&mreq,sizeof(mreq));

    bind(socket_fd,(sockaddr *)&muladdr,sizeof(muladdr));

    char buf[100];
    memset(buf,0,100);

    long lSize=recvfrom(socket_fd,buf,100,0,NULL,NULL);
    if(lSize)
    {
        printf("recvd data: %s\n",buf);
    }

    close(socket_fd);

    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t pp;
    pthread_create(&pp,NULL,recvd,NULL);
    sleep(2);
    long socket_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);

    int ttl=25;
    setsockopt(socket_fd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));

    struct sockaddr_in muladdr;
    memset(&muladdr,0,sizeof(muladdr));
    muladdr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    muladdr.sin_port=htons(3454);
    inet_aton("224.1.2.3",(in_addr*)&muladdr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    char arr[]="Hello World!";
    printf("sending data\n");

    long result=sendto(socket_fd,arr,sizeof(arr),0,(sockaddr *)&muladdr,sizeof(muladdr));
    if(result==-1)
    {
        perror("Error in sending data");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("sent data\n");


    pthread_join(pp,NULL);

    close(socket_fd);

    return 0;

}
```

I have disabled firewall as well but still no luck.

Comment: How are you sending multicast stream? which mac address are you using, make sure u use multicast MAC?

Comment: @Vikash do you mean the ioctl call with option  SIOCGIFFLAGS  to get interface's flags?

Comment: No, he means that sending to a multicast address requires that the ethernet destination address currently reflects a multicast channel.

Comment: I compiled the posted code on linux 16.04 with `gcc` with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Wconversion`  The result is a few dozen errors and warnings.  For instance:  "... Error ... 'in_addr' not declared"  and '... Error ... 'sockaddr' not declared" and lots and lots more error and warning messages.  Strongly suggest always compiling with the warnings enabled, then fix those warnings

Comment: When a function parameter is not going to be used...  For `main()` can use the signature `int main( void )`.  for other functions,  such as: `void* recvd(void* t)`  the first statement in the body of the function should be: `(void)t;`

Comment: This is the syntax for `setsockopt()`  `int setsockopt(int sockfd, int level, int optname, const void *optval, socklen_t optlen);`  Notice there are 5 parameters.  however, the posted code: `setsockopt(socket_fd, IPPROTO_IP,IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));` is passing a `size_t` rather than a `socklen_t` for the 5th parameter.

Comment: regarding: `long socket_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);`   The `socket()` signature is: `int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);`  Notice the returned type is `int`, not `long`  and passing that 'long` as the first parameter to `setsockopt()` generates a compiler warning.  Suggest correcting the declaration og `socket_fd`

Comment: everywhere in the posted code that says: `in_addr` should say: `struct in_addr`

Comment: the `sendto()` syntax is: `ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);`  1) the return type is: `ssize_t`, not `long`'  the 5th parameter has type `const struct sockaddr*`  NOT 'sockaddr`  the last parameter has type: `socklen_t` NOT `size_t`  Please pay attention to the parameter types and return types for the functions you are invoking.

Comment: after the call to: `sendto()`, when an error occurs, the function: `exit()` is being called, however, before calling `exit()`, need to close the open `socket` and kill the thread.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.

Comment: the syntax for function: `recvfrom()` is: `ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);`  1) the return type is: `ssize_t` not `long`.  2) the type of the last parameter is: `socklen_t` not `size_t`.    Strongly suggest reading/understanding the MAN pages for those functions that you invoke.

Comment: the function: `recvfrom()` does NOT terminate the input data with a NUL byte.  so this statement: `printf("recvd data: %s\n",buf);` will have undefined behavior.  Suggest using the returned value from `recvfrom()` to index into `buf` to insert a NUL byte before calling `printf()`

Comment: when calling system functions (socket(), bind(), setsockopt()`, etc. always check the returned value to assure the function was successful.  And when not successful, output the appropriate error message to `stderr`.

Comment: the posted code is using `UDP` protocol for communication.  There is no guarantee that UDP packets will ever arrive at their intended destination.  The UDP protocol is a `one way` protocol, so the code should not be using that single socket for two way communication.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 100.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names through out the code.

Comment: @user3629249 thanks for the suggestions. Can you tell me the solution for my problem

Comment: in the posted code, in the thread, there is the statement: `close(socket_fd);` just before the call to `return` the preferred statement is a call to `pthread_exit();`

Comment: I have never had to write code to receive multicast packets, so I would have to research it, just as you should be doing.